# We have used stash and are migrating to Bitbucket. How can we migrate pull request data and review comments from stash to bitbucket?

Tags: pull-request, bitbucket-server

We have used stash and are migrating to Bitbucket. How can we migrate pull request data and review comments from stash to bitbucket?

what is the best way to do this?

Anyone has similar experience?

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving to Bitbucket Server 4.x it is a lot like any other Stash upgrade you've done before. The product was renamed but the underlying architecture it's much the same. See the upgrade guide at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-server-upgrade-guide-776640551.html